# Bootstrap collapsed menu scrolling issue

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having a scrolling issue on Bootstrap collapsed menu on `navbar-fixed-top`, when it's collapsed menu doesn't scroll vertically but the page start scrolling. 
Everything works fine when I set `navbar-static-top` but I really need to stick navbar to the top.
Any help is highly appreciable. Thanks 
Please check it this code below, you can also check the code on [**Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/KaEV4XLNP2)

```css
.navbar-brand { position: relative; z-index: 2; }

.navbar-nav.navbar-right .btn { position: relative; z-index: 2; padding: 4px 20px; margin: 10px auto; transition: transform 0.3s; }

.navbar .navbar-collapse { position: relative; overflow: hidden !important; }
.navbar .navbar-collapse .navbar-right > li:last-child { padding-left: 22px; }

.navbar .nav-collapse { position: absolute; z-index: 1; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; margin: 0; padding-right: 120px; padding-left: 80px; width: 100%; }
.navbar.navbar-default .nav-collapse { background-color: #f8f8f8; }
.navbar.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse { background-color: #222; }
.navbar .nav-collapse .navbar-form { border-width: 0; box-shadow: none; }
.nav-collapse>li { float: right; }

.btn.btn-circle { border-radius: 50px; }
.btn.btn-outline { background-color: transparent; }

.navbar-nav.navbar-right .btn:not(.collapsed) {
    background-color: rgb(111, 84, 153);
    border-color: rgb(111, 84, 153);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.navbar.navbar-default .nav-collapse,
.navbar.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse {
    height: auto !important;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
    transform: translate(0px,-50px);
}
.navbar.navbar-default .nav-collapse.in,
.navbar.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse.in {
    transform: translate(0px,0px);
}
#Searchbox{width:500px;}


@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar .navbar-collapse .navbar-right > li:last-child { padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px; } 
    
    .navbar .nav-collapse { margin: 7.5px auto; padding: 0; }
    .navbar .nav-collapse .navbar-form { margin: 0; }
    .nav-collapse>li { float: none; }
    
    .navbar.navbar-default .nav-collapse,
    .navbar.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse {
        transform: translate(-100%,0px);
    }
    .navbar.navbar-default .nav-collapse.in,
    .navbar.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse.in {
        transform: translate(0px,0px);
    }
    
    .navbar.navbar-default .nav-collapse.slide-down,
    .navbar.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse.slide-down {
        transform: translate(0px,-100%);
    }
    .navbar.navbar-default .nav-collapse.in.slide-down,
    .navbar.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse.in.slide-down {
        transform: translate(0px,0px);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-3">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>
       
    
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-3">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown "><a href="#" id="drop1" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button">Music <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="drop1">
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#" role="menuitem">Grones</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#" role="menuitem">Nach</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#" role="menuitem">Zpu</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#" role="menuitem">Madnass</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
          
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Works</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li>
              <a class="btn btn-default collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#nav-collapse3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="nav-collapse3">Search</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <div class="collapse nav navbar-nav nav-collapse slide-down" id="nav-collapse3">
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container -->
    </nav><!-- /.navbar -->
    
<div class="container body-content" style="margin-top:60px;">
  <div class="row" style="padding:10px;">
          asdfasdf<br>
          asdfas
          df<br>
          sadf<br>
          asdf<br>
          a<br>
          sdf<br>
          sad<br>
          f<br>
          sadf<br>
          as<br>
          df<br>
          sadf<br>
          sa<br>
          df<br>
                    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule is causing your issue:

```
.navbar .navbar-collapse { position: relative; overflow: hidden !important; }
```

Remove `overflow: hidden !important`

See working example Snippet. * I also adjusted your search button so it's not cut off.

```css
body {
  padding-top: 70px;
}
.navbar-brand {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
.navbar-nav.navbar-right .btn {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 4px 20px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}
.navbar .navbar-collapse {
  position: relative;
}
.navbar .navbar-collapse .navbar-right > li:last-child {
  padding-left: 22px;
  right: 15px;
}
.navbar .nav-collapse {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-right: 120px;
  padding-left: 80px;
  width: 100%;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .nav-collapse {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}
.navbar.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse {
  background-color: #222;
}
.navbar .nav-collapse .navbar-form {
  border-width: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.nav-collapse>li {
  float: right;
}
.btn.btn-circle {
  border-radius: 50px;
}
.btn.btn-outline {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-nav.navbar-right .btn:not(.collapsed) {
  background-color: rgb(111, 84, 153);
  border-color: rgb(111, 84, 153);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.navbar.navbar-default .nav-collapse,
.navbar.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse {
  height: auto !important;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
  transform: translate(0px, -50px);
}
.navbar.navbar-default .nav-collapse.in,
.navbar.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse.in {
  transform: translate(0px, 0px);
}
#Searchbox {
  width: 500px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar .navbar-collapse .navbar-right > li:last-child {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    right: 0;
  }
  .navbar .nav-collapse {
    margin: 7.5px auto;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .navbar .nav-collapse .navbar-form {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .nav-collapse>li {
    float: none;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-default .nav-collapse,
  .navbar.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0px);
  }
  .navbar.navbar-default .nav-collapse.in,
  .navbar.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse.in {
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  }
  .navbar.navbar-default .nav-collapse.slide-down,
  .navbar.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse.slide-down {
    transform: translate(0px, -100%);
  }
  .navbar.navbar-default .nav-collapse.in.slide-down,
  .navbar.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse.in.slide-down {
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-3"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-3">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li class="dropdown "><a href="#" id="drop1" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button">Music <b class="caret"></b></a>

          <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="drop1">
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#" role="menuitem">Grones</a>

            </li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#" role="menuitem">Nach</a>

            </li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#" role="menuitem">Zpu</a>

            </li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#" role="menuitem">Madnass</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">About</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Works</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">News</a>

        </li>
        <li> <a class="btn btn-default collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#nav-collapse3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="nav-collapse3">Search</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="collapse nav navbar-nav nav-collapse slide-down" id="nav-collapse3">
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>

          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <div class="well">well</div>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a million man, you are a life saver, I almost broke my head. too bad I am not a CSS guy. Thanks again

Comment: No problem and glad I could help!.